# Describe all the group homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}_{24}$ to $\mathbb{Z}_{18}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Maybe I have a pretty dumb question, but I'm not able to clarify it on my own. I'm beginning with homomorphims and I'm somewhat stuck with the solution to the second problem that appears in this [document](http://campus.lakeforest.edu/trevino/Fall2014/Math330/Homework8Solutions.pdf).

It states

[image]

I kind of understand it, but the only part I don't get is why the set of allowable $k$'s is just composed of $\{0,3, 6, 9, 12, 15\}$. Why doesn't it continue with $18,\ 21$, and so on since they also meet the constraint $k \equiv 0\ \mathrm{mod}\ 3$.

To be more concise, what does it tell me that I have to ''stop'' in $15$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In $\mathbb{Z}_{18}$, $18 = 0$, $21 = 3$, $24 = 6$, etc. They're already on the list.